# When are PID released?

Tags: unix, process, fork

As far as I know (pardon my ignorance on the subject), when a process `fork()`s:

- Each child gets assigned its own PID
- After a child has exited, the parent is still able to query the child's PID with `waitpid()`

Does that mean that:

- Because this PID is still "queryable" from the parent, it's still locked and not reusable by the system?
- Or is the number just associated to the parent so that it can know it's exited, and get the exit status code, but in parallel the PID is made available to the system again? In that case, does that mean that this PID could not be reused for a child process for this parent? That would mean that there is an upper limit on the number of processes a parent can span in its lifetime, which would be surprising to me.

I'd be grateful if you can clarify that for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most UNIXes, unless the parent specifically requests otherwise, until it waits for the child, the child process still exists in the system process table as a zombie process. So the PID cannot be re-used.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Is `waitpid()` the one and only way to release the PID then? And does that mean that it can only be called once, or it would return incorrect information the 2nd time it's called?

Comment: It's not the only way. You can also use `wait`. You can also terminate and let your parent clean up after you (your child becomes an orphan your parent inherits). Also, most UNIXes have some way to request the system automatically reap your zombies, often by ignoring SIGCHLD. The second call gets correct information, but different. Most likely, it will be told that PID no longer exists.

Comment: Ok, so if I want to get the exit status code, I'll have just one change to get it?

Comment: Sorry, typo, I meant one **chance** to get it. I've just tested that, and strangely enough, even though subsequent calls to `waitpid()` return `-1`, they do populate `& status` with the same value as the first call. So it's still stored somewhere and made available to the parent? But I guess we have no guarantee that this data will be correct, in the (unlikely) event that the PID is reused later on for a child of this same parent?

Comment: @Benjamin: No, it just stayed in `status` the whole time because you never changed it.